# Disable Button on Radio Based in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, radio-group, angularjs-ng-disabled

i want to disable upload button until not selected of any radio button when i select AAA Radio button then button is enable but when select BBB Then Button is Disable and Select 01 or 02 then Button is Enable Its Solutions[See Below the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r20wJ.png)

Comment: Share the code done till now, best will be a working example and expected result!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.